# asp.net mvc route constraints regular expression

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, dynamic-pages

I want to server dynamic pages using url without controller and action on the basis of page title
default url : `domain.com/pages/details/1`
I want this to be server as
`domain.com/title-of-dynamic-page-in-db-space-replaced-with-dash`
`domain.com/about-us`
`domain.com/contact-us`

if I am doing this without dash than routing will confuse with `controller` name
thats why I added dash `-` for dynamic pages

my action looks like this

```
    // GET: Pages/View/5
    public ActionResult View(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Page page = db.Pages.First(p => p.name_english == id.Replace("-"," "));
        if (page == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }
```

my routes are

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "aaaaa",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "pages", action = "view" },
            constraints: new { id = @"^[A-Za-z\d-]+$" } //*********help needed in this line ******************************
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

above Constrain `^[A-Za-z\d-]+$`
accepts  `alpha(optional)` `numeric(optional)` and `dash(optional)`

while I need `alpha(optional)` `numeric(optional)` and `dash(*mandatory*)`

this way routing  engine will not confuse page title with controller/action as I will make sure my name of dynamic page will contain space(i m replacing with dash)
and my controller/action will not be named contained dash

also tell me, is this approach ok or not, is there any other optimized solution for this?

Comment: `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$`

Comment: ya this worked :) , Is this approach ok, or there is some other best solution?

Comment: Its fine. You need to use a route constraint to meet your requirements.

Comment: @FakhrAlam Are you sure `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$` works for you? You say you *need `alpha(optional)` `numeric(optional)` and `dash(*mandatory*)`*, but the above pattern requires *alpha* chars at the start. Please make your question clearer.

Comment: you are right @Wilktor, hypen at start and end do not work. Please correct this reg exp

Comment: and also there should be at least 1 alph or num

Comment: I replaced it with `^([-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*[-]*)+$` will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the following snippet will work for you.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "aaaaa",
        url: "{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "pages", action = "view" },
        constraints: new { id = @"^([-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*[-]*)+$" } //*********this should work**
    );

    //---------------------------------------
    // ^([-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*[-]*)+$
    //---------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think constraints object, at least now, requires actual Constraint class, and not a string